# Proving that a composition of bounded operator and trace class operator is trace class

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, trace

[image]

This is a fact from Wikipedia, and I tried to prove this fact from the definition of boundedness and trace norm, but cannot find a way. Could anyone please tell me how to prove it?